# Android-studio: gradle throws app:mergeDebugResources failed error. AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon startup failed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

While building new android app in android studio, gradle throws *`app:mergeDebugResources failed`* error. 
After running assembleDebug task in gradle, I get the following log:

```
Executing tasks: [assembleDebug]
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 3: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: ()*+,-./ ���A2!�������������������� @!���cf
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error output: ���$ @�������������{ !"#`abcdefghijklmno�����������������������������������1$����������������!��������������������;840
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error output:     ������������������������������1*m�����������������������������!����������   
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error output: 
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error output: 0123456789:;<=>? �����������������������0h!PQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_ @@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO0123456789ABCDEFUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUnpOlnpLbnpTc
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error output: ��i����--dirEnables: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 4: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: cannot open add-resource: No such file
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 4: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: resources: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 5: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: cannot open config: No such file
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 5: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: Syntax:: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 6: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 1: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: @8@@@@hh�������������%�%�%��0��%�%�%�/&�/&�/&P�td� � � $�$�Q�td���  /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2гY>Y7?A�Z@?_K�ݓ=KMGT4�  a���������������������,��pqrstuvwxyz{|}~ @! !#$%: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 1: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: ELF: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #1: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 1: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: ELF: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #1: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 1: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: @8@@@@hh�������������%�%�%��0��%�%�%�/&�/&�/&P�td� � � $�$�Q�td���  /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2гY>Y7?A�Z@?_K�ݓ=KMGT4�  a���������������������,��pqrstuvwxyz{|}~ @! !#$%: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #2: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 3: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: ()*+,-./ ���A2!�������������������� @!���cf
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #2: Unexpected error output: ���$ @�������������{ !"#`abcdefghijklmno�����������������������������������1$����������������!��������������������;840
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #2: Unexpected error output:     ������������������������������1*m�����������������������������!����������   
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #2: Unexpected error output: 
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #2: Unexpected error output: 0123456789:;<=>? �����������������������0h!PQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_ @@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO0123456789ABCDEFUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUnpOlnpLbnpTc
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #2: Unexpected error output: ��i����--dirEnables: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #2: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 4: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: cannot open add-resource: No such file
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #2: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 4: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: resources: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #2: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 5: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: cannot open config: No such file
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #2: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 5: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: Syntax:: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #2: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 6: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #2: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 1: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: @8@@@@hh�������������%�%�%��0��%�%�%�/&�/&�/&P�td� � � $�$�Q�td���  /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2гY>Y7?A�Z@?_K�ݓ=KMGT4�  a���������������������,��pqrstuvwxyz{|}~ @! !#$%: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #2: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 1: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: ELF: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #1: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 3: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: ()*+,-./ ���A2!�������������������� @!���cf
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #1: Unexpected error output: ���$ @�������������{ !"#`abcdefghijklmno�����������������������������������1$����������������!��������������������;840
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #1: Unexpected error output:     ������������������������������1*m�����������������������������!����������   
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #1: Unexpected error output: 
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #1: Unexpected error output: 0123456789:;<=>? �����������������������0h!PQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_ @@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO0123456789ABCDEFUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUnpOlnpLbnpTc
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #1: Unexpected error output: ��i����--dirEnables: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #1: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 4: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: cannot open add-resource: No such file
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #1: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 4: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: resources: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #1: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 5: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: cannot open config: No such file
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #1: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 5: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: Syntax:: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #1: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 6: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #3: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 1: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: @8@@@@hh�������������%�%�%��0��%�%�%�/&�/&�/&P�td� � � $�$�Q�td���  /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2гY>Y7?A�Z@?_K�ݓ=KMGT4�  a���������������������,��pqrstuvwxyz{|}~ @! !#$%: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #3: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 3: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: ()*+,-./ ���A2!�������������������� @!���cf
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #3: Unexpected error output: ���$ @�������������{ !"#`abcdefghijklmno�����������������������������������1$����������������!��������������������;840
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #3: Unexpected error output:     ������������������������������1*m�����������������������������!����������   
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #3: Unexpected error output: 
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #3: Unexpected error output: 0123456789:;<=>? �����������������������0h!PQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_ @@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO0123456789ABCDEFUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUnpOlnpLbnpTc
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #3: Unexpected error output: ��i����--dirEnables: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #5: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 3: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: ()*+,-./ ���A2!�������������������� @!���cf
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #5: Unexpected error output: ���$ @�������������{ !"#`abcdefghijklmno�����������������������������������1$����������������!��������������������;840
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #5: Unexpected error output:     ������������������������������1*m�����������������������������!����������   
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #5: Unexpected error output: 
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #5: Unexpected error output: 0123456789:;<=>? �����������������������0h!PQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_ @@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO0123456789ABCDEFUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUnpOlnpLbnpTc
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #5: Unexpected error output: ��i����--dirEnables: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #5: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 5: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: cannot open config: No such file
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #5: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 5: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: Syntax:: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #5: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 6: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #5: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 1: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: @8@@@@hh�������������%�%�%��0��%�%�%�/&�/&�/&P�td� � � $�$�Q�td���  /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2гY>Y7?A�Z@?_K�ݓ=KMGT4�  a���������������������,��pqrstuvwxyz{|}~ @! !#$%: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #4: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 1: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: ELF: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #4: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 3: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: ()*+,-./ ���A2!�������������������� @!���cf
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #4: Unexpected error output: ���$ @�������������{ !"#`abcdefghijklmno�����������������������������������1$����������������!��������������������;840
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #4: Unexpected error output:     ������������������������������1*m�����������������������������!����������   
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #4: Unexpected error output: 
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #4: Unexpected error output: 0123456789:;<=>? �����������������������0h!PQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_ @@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO0123456789ABCDEFUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUnpOlnpLbnpTc
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #4: Unexpected error output: ��i����--dirEnables: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #6: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 3: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: ()*+,-./ ���A2!�������������������� @!���cf
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #6: Unexpected error output: ���$ @�������������{ !"#`abcdefghijklmno�����������������������������������1$����������������!��������������������;840
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #6: Unexpected error output:     ������������������������������1*m�����������������������������!����������   
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #6: Unexpected error output: 
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #6: Unexpected error output: 0123456789:;<=>? �����������������������0h!PQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_ @@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO0123456789ABCDEFUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUnpOlnpLbnpTc
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #7: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 1: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: @8@@@@hh�������������%�%�%��0��%�%�%�/&�/&�/&P�td� � � $�$�Q�td���  /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2гY>Y7?A�Z@?_K�ݓ=KMGT4�  a���������������������,��pqrstuvwxyz{|}~ @! !#$%: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #7: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 1: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: ELF: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #6: Unexpected error output: ��i����--dirEnables: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #6: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 1: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: @8@@@@hh�������������%�%�%��0��%�%�%�/&�/&�/&P�td� � � $�$�Q�td���  /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2гY>Y7?A�Z@?_K�ݓ=KMGT4�  a���������������������,��pqrstuvwxyz{|}~ @! !#$%: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #6: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 1: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: ELF: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #6: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 4: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: cannot open add-resource: No such file
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #7: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 3: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: ()*+,-./ ���A2!�������������������� @!���cf
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #6: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 4: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: resources: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #7: Unexpected error output: ���$ @�������������{ !"#`abcdefghijklmno�����������������������������������1$����������������!��������������������;840
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #7: Unexpected error output:     ������������������������������1*m�����������������������������!����������   
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #7: Unexpected error output: 
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #7: Unexpected error output: 0123456789:;<=>? �����������������������0h!PQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_ @@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO0123456789ABCDEFUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUnpOlnpLbnpTc
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #7: Unexpected error output: ��i����--dirEnables: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #7: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 4: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: resources: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #7: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 5: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: cannot open config: No such file
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #7: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 6: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #6: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 5: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: cannot open config: No such file
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #6: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 5: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: Syntax:: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #6: Unexpected error output: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: 6: /home/prashant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux.jar/71853ef49111e384b402b769f4fd71ec/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux/aapt2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-linux Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
```

Comment: "This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does" - if you can't find an issue already, open one in the issue tracker

Comment: Did you try to invalidate caches  (File->Invalidate caches / restart) your Android Studio?

Comment: Also you can try to remove all build folders and rebuild project.

Comment: @Valdemar Already tried the steps before posting my question.

Comment: @ahmetkoçu Tried rebuilding project, but this didn't help.

Comment: It worked when I ran on 64 bit Ubuntu. Building with older version of Gradle and Android sdk, asks me to update it to latest one. How can I build my app on my 32 bit 14.04 Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to run Android Studio on Linux 32 bit, but that system is **not** supported. Android Studio only works on Windows (both 32 and 64 bit), MacOS (64 bit) and Linux (64 bit).

More info: https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads