# AAPT2 complains about a non-existent syntax error

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-jetpack-compose

I'm creating a Jetpack Compose app and I kept getting this message:

```
AAPT2 aapt2-7.3.1-8691043-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error output: /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2aa1849659ea6e682659b94654585970/transformed/aapt2-7.3.1-8691043-linux/aapt2[1]: syntax error: unexpected '('
```

I have checked all of my XML files in my project and all of them are valid. I also included a Gradle log if you know why did this happen:

```
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:parseDebugLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugManifestForPackage UP-TO-DATE
AAPT2 aapt2-7.3.1-8691043-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error output: /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2aa1849659ea6e682659b94654585970/transformed/aapt2-7.3.1-8691043-linux/aapt2[1]: syntax error: unexpected '('
> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform appcompat-1.5.0.aar (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/40f398f695812d444678d4d423ac1c30/transformed/appcompat-1.5.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-7.3.1-8691043-linux Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
13 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 12 up-to-date
```

Comment: Looks like a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54843475/android-studio-gradle-throws-appmergedebugresources-failed-error-aapt2-aapt2

Comment: I don't think so, mine doesn't have those gibberish stuff